# jQuery get value of select onChange

Tags: jquery, select

I was under the impression that I could get the value of a select input by doing this `$(this).val();` and applying the `onchange` parameter to the select field.

It would appear it only works if I reference the ID.

How do I do it using this.

Answer (score 1892, accepted):

Try this-

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

You can also reference with onchange event-

```js
function getval(sel)
{
    alert(sel.value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getval(this);">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I know this is quite late but if you are using the keyboard (tabbing) to navigate a form and use the up/down arrows to choose from a dropdown list then FireFox (22.0) does not trigger the change event. You need to additionally bind keypress for FireFox. Additional Info: jQuery 1.10.2 using the syntax $('select').on('change', function(){ /* do seomthing */ });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85070/discussion-between-phoneixs-and-monkeyzeus).

Comment: If you are using arrow functions, 'this' will not work because it may not be bound the element identified from the JQuery tag. 
If you wanted to use arrow functions then an alternative would be:
$('#id').on('change', (evt) => {
     console.log(evt.currentTarget.value);
})

Answer (score 138):

This is helped for me.

For select:

```
$('select_tags').on('change', function() {
    alert( $(this).find(":selected").val() );
});
```

For radio/checkbox:

```
$('radio_tags').on('change', function() {
    alert( $(this).find(":checked").val() );
});
```

Answer (score 131):

> I was under the impression that I could get the value of a select
>   input by doing this $(this).val();

This works if you subscribe unobtrusively (which is the recommended approach):

```
$('#id_of_field').change(function() {
    // $(this).val() will work here
});
```

if you use `onselect` and mix markup with script you need to pass a reference to the current element:

```
onselect="foo(this);"
```

and then:

```
function foo(element) {
    // $(element).val() will give you what you are looking for
}
```

Answer (score 26):

```
$('#select_id').on('change', function()
{
    alert(this.value); //or alert($(this).val());
});



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select_id">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 26):

Arrow function has a different scope than function,
`this.value` will give undefined for an arrow function.
To fix use

```
$('select').on('change',(event) => {
     alert( event.target.value );
 });
```

Answer (score 26):

```
$('#select-id').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: if somebody also need to get the text of the option, here is it
$(this).find('option:selected').text();

Answer (score 25):

Try the event delegation method, this works in almost all cases.

```
$(document.body).on('change',"#selectID",function (e) {
   //doStuff
   var optVal= $("#selectID option:selected").val();
});
```

Answer (score 15):

You can try this (using [**jQuery**](https://jquery.com/))-

```js
$('select').on('change', function()
{
    alert( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Or you can use simple Javascript like this-

```js
function getNewVal(item)
{
    alert(item.value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="getNewVal(this);">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 11):

This is what worked for me. Tried everything else with no luck:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Example: Change event on a select</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function changeEventHandler(event) {
        alert('You like ' + event.target.value + ' ice cream.');
      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <label>Choose an ice cream flavor: </label>
    <select size="1" onchange="changeEventHandler(event);">
      <option>chocolate</option>
      <option>strawberry</option>
      <option>vanilla</option>
    </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Taken from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Answer (score 10):

For all selects, invoke this function.

```
$('select').on('change', function()
{
    alert( this.value );
});
```

For only one select:

```
$('#select_id')
```

Answer (score 8):

Look for jQuery [site](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1">
  <select class="target">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

jQuery's example:

To add a validity test to all text input elements:

```
$( "input[type='text']" ).change(function() {
  // Check input( $( this ).val() ) for validity here
});
```

Answer (score 6):

i have an example to help in new ideas.
i hope this will help anybody.

```
$('#editpricelist_box').change(function ($e){
    $('input[name="edit_unit_price"]').val(parseFloat(this.val()).toFixed(2));
    console.log(this.val());
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#id").change(function() {
      var value = jQuery(this).children(":selected").attr("value");
     alert(value);

    });
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me share an example which I developed with BS4, thymeleaf and Spring boot.

I am using two SELECTs, where the second ("subtopic") gets filled by an AJAX call based on the selection of the first("topic").

First, the thymeleaf snippet:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label th:for="topicId" th:text="#{label.topic}">Topic</label>
     <select class="custom-select"
             th:id="topicId" th:name="topicId"
             th:field="*{topicId}"
             th:errorclass="is-invalid" required>
         <option value="" selected
                 th:text="#{option.select}">Select
         </option>
         <optgroup th:each="topicGroup : ${topicGroups}"
                   th:label="${topicGroup}">
             <option th:each="topicItem : ${topics}"
                     th:if="${topicGroup == topicItem.grp} "
                     th:value="${{topicItem.baseIdentity.id}}"
                     th:text="${topicItem.name}"
                     th:selected="${{topicItem.baseIdentity.id==topicId}}">
             </option>
         </optgroup>
         <option th:each="topicIter : ${topics}"
                 th:if="${topicIter.grp == ''} "
                 th:value="${{topicIter.baseIdentity.id}}"
                 th:text="${topicIter.name}"
                 th:selected="${{topicIter.baseIdentity?.id==topicId}}">
         </option>
     </select>
     <small id="topicHelp" class="form-text text-muted"
            th:text="#{label.topic.tt}">select</small>
</div><!-- .form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="subtopicsId" th:text="#{label.subtopicsId}">subtopics</label>
    <select class="custom-select"
            id="subtopicsId" name="subtopicsId"
            th:field="*{subtopicsId}"
            th:errorclass="is-invalid" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="" disabled
                th:text="#{option.multiple.optional}">Select
        </option>
        <option th:each="subtopicsIter : ${subtopicsList}"
                th:value="${{subtopicsIter.baseIdentity.id}}"
                th:text="${subtopicsIter.name}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <small id="subtopicsHelp" class="form-text text-muted"
           th:unless="${#fields.hasErrors('subtopicsId')}"
           th:text="#{label.subtopics.tt}">select</small>
    <small id="subtopicsIdError" class="invalid-feedback"
           th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('subtopicsId')}"
           th:errors="*{subtopicsId}">Errors</small>
</div><!-- .form-group -->
```

I am iterating over a list of topics that is stored in the model context, showing all groups with their topics, and after that all topics that do not have a group.
BaseIdentity is an @Embedded composite key BTW.

Now, here's the jQuery that handles changes:

```
$('#topicId').change(function () {
    selectedOption = $(this).val();
    if (selectedOption === "") {
        $('#subtopicsId').prop('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
        $("#subtopicsId option").slice(1).remove(); // keep first
    } else {
        $('#subtopicsId').prop('disabled', false)
        var orig = $(location).attr('origin');
        var url = orig + "/getsubtopics/" + selectedOption;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
           success: function (response) {
                  var len = response.length;
                    $("#subtopicsId option[value!='']").remove(); // keep first 
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var id = response[i]['baseIdentity']['id'];
                        var name = response[i]['name'];
                        $("#subtopicsId").append("<option value='" + id + "'>" + name + "</option>");
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                }
        });
    }
}).change(); // and call it once defined
```

The initial call of change() makes sure it will be executed on page re-load or if a value has been preselected by some initialization in the backend.

BTW: I am using "manual" form validation (see "is-valid"/"is-invalid"), because I (and users) didn't like that BS4 marks non-required empty fields as green. But that's byond scope of this Q and if you are interested then I can post it also.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if these are not working, it might be because the DOM has not loaded and your element was not found yet.

To fix, put the script at the end of body or use document ready

```
$.ready(function() {
    $("select").on('change', function(ret) {  
         console.log(ret.target.value)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

only with JS

```
 let select=document.querySelectorAll('select') 
  select.forEach(function(el) {
    el.onchange =  function(){
     alert(this.value);
      
  }}
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to add,
who needs full custom header functionality

```
   function addSearchControls(json) {
        $("#tblCalls thead").append($("#tblCalls thead tr:first").clone());
        $("#tblCalls thead tr:eq(1) th").each(function (index) {
            // For text inputs
            if (index != 1 && index != 2) {
                $(this).replaceWith('<th><input type="text" placeholder=" ' + $(this).html() + ' ara"></input></th>');
                var searchControl = $("#tblCalls thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(" + index + ") input");
                searchControl.on("keyup", function () {
                    table.column(index).search(searchControl.val()).draw();
                })
            }
            // For DatePicker inputs
            else if (index == 1) {
                $(this).replaceWith('<th><input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="' + $(this).html() + ' ara" class="tblCalls-search-date datepicker" /></th>');

                $('.tblCalls-search-date').on('keyup click change', function () {
                    var i = $(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
                    var v = $(this).val();  // getting search input value
                    table.columns(index).search(v).draw();
                });

                $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    altFieldTimeOnly: false,
                    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    altTimeFormat: "h:m",
                    altField: "#tarih-db",
                    monthNames: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
                    dayNamesMin: ["Pa", "Pt", "Sl", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Ct"],
                    firstDay: 1,
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    showOn: "button",
                    showAnim: 'slideDown',
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    autoSize: true,
                    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: false,
                    buttonText: "Tarih Seçiniz",
                    closeText: "Temizle"
                });
                $(document).on("click", ".ui-datepicker-close", function () {
                    $('.datepicker').val("");
                    table.columns(5).search("").draw();
                });
            }
            // For DropDown inputs
            else if (index == 2) {
                $(this).replaceWith('<th><select id="filter_comparator" class="styled-select yellow rounded"><option value="select">Seç</option><option value="eq">=</option><option value="gt">&gt;=</option><option value="lt">&lt;=</option><option value="ne">!=</option></select><input type="text" id="filter_value"></th>');

                var selectedOperator;
                $('#filter_comparator').on('change', function () {
                    var i = $(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
                    var v = $(this).val();  // getting search input value
                    selectedOperator = v;
                    if(v=="select")
                        table.columns(index).search('select|0').draw();
                    $('#filter_value').val("");
                });

                $('#filter_value').on('keyup click change', function () {
                    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                    if (keycode == '13') {
                        var i = $(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
                        var v = $(this).val();  // getting search input value
                        table.columns(index).search(selectedOperator + '|' + v).draw();
                    }
                });
            }
        })

    }
```