# How to get dynamically a value of a select tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get dynamically the value of a select tag in my form.
I do this actually

```
<select name="media_types_id" id="type">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<script>
    var option = $("#type option:selected").val();
    console.log(option);
</script>
```

but this return the value of the option selected and it doesn't change when I change the option in my form. i select 1 and if I select 2 after it stays at value 1...

Comment: See this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind change event to your select list:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
     $("#type").change(function() {
     console.log($(this).val());
    });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind `change` event to your `<select>` element and use its value:

```
$("#type").on("change", function() {
    var option = this.value;
    console.log(option);
});
```

Also note that event binding should be done when the DOM is loaded, so either place this code right before `</body>` or use `$(function() { });` handler.

Answer (score 3):

Try Following use `change()` event to get the selected value of a drop down list

```
$("#type").on("change",function(){
        var Option = this.val();
        console.log(Option);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

but your code runs globally. so for the first time , when page loads 1 is the selected value.

try your code inside `change` event

i.e.

```
$('#type').on("change",function(){
    var option = $("option:selected",this).val();
    console.log(option);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use event handlers.

Event handlers call a function every time something happens.

**Pure JS**

```
var option = document.getElementById("type").value;
document.getElementById("type").onchange = function(e) {
    option = this.value;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/FnT9T/3/