# Call function based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, function, arguments

I have the following dropdown

```
<select onchange="myFunc(argument here)" id="propertydropdown">
<option value="tags">blah</option>
<option value="tags2">blahblah</option>
<option value="tags3">blahblahblah</option>
</select>
```

how do i get the argument to be the value of the option currently selected?

Comment: @Bergi - ^^^ sounds like an answer!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of select onChange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange) or [How to get the selected value of dropdownlist using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript) if you prefer a non-jQuery question (the answer is the same)

Answer (score 4):

Simply `myFunc(this.value)`, since [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) == `document.getElementByID("propertydropdow")` in the handler

Comment: yup that's the answer thanks!

Comment: how would I do this if I have <input onchange="tcUpdate(argument)" type="color" name="favcolor">

Comment: @Lemonio: It's the same actually?

Comment: i don't think my onchange is working then, though maybe i'm just doing something else wrong

Comment: nvm found a workaround

Comment: if the text contain spaces I can only access the first word

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you could pass the selected value as an argument, but what you could do is within the handler itself use `this` to work out the value (`this` will be the select):

```
function myFunc() {

    var value = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value;

   // ...do stuff

}
```

You might even be able to do `onclick="myFunc( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );"`, but I haven't tried that.