# Execute javascript function on option value?

Tags: javascript, onclick, onchange

Is it possible to execute a javascript function on individual 's in a dropdown menu?
I have this so far

```
 <select class="btn dropdown-toggle" ONCHANGE="swapContent('+value+');">

<option onClick="return false" ONCHANGE="javascript:swapContent('Prva');">Kategorija</option>
<option onClick="return false" ONCHANGE="javascript:swapContent('Druga');">2</option>
<option onClick="return false" ONCHANGE="javascript:swapContent('Treca');">3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

But i have no luck :(

**EDITED**
Lots of you gave me an asnwer, even i got vote down but this is not working with AJAX, i will extend my question, with function:

```
function swapContent(cv) {
    $("#myDiv").html('').show();
    var url = "ajax.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
}
```

And here is simple ajax.php

```
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
echo $contentVar;
```

**SOLUTION**

```
    <select class="btn dropdown-toggle" ONCHANGE="swapContent(this.value);">

<option>Kategorija</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Comment: @PeteThorne You cannot expect that every user has got expirence with jquery or is allowed to use jquery.

Comment: try my updated example. you should remove the ONCHANGE and ONCLICK attributes from your <option> tags.

Comment: also you have an extra ending tag symbol in your first line :)

Answer (score 1):

why `onclick` and `onchange` for `options` tag?  Instead it is enough to have **`onchange`** event in **`select`** tag.

```
<select class="btn dropdown-toggle" ONCHANGE="swapContent(this)">

<option value='Prva'>Kategorija</option>
<option value='Druga'>2</option>
<option value='Treca'>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
function swapContent(that) {
    alert(that.value);
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/3aq3v/1/)

Hope you understand.

Comment: I understant, this with alert is ok, but i have edite my question

Comment: If i do this <select class="btn dropdown-toggle" ONCHANGE="swapContent('this');"> Then is working, but i just got echo this :)))

Comment: @Gorostas `'this'` is a string representation.  try without quotes "swapContent(this)"

Comment: Of course, if i to 'this' I got something, if i do only this i got nothing, in Ajax.php i have simple       $contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
echo $contentVar;

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function swapContent(cv) {
    $("#myDiv").html('').show();
    var url = "ajax.html";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
       $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select onchange="swapContent(this);">

<option>Kategorija</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @kwikness as far as I know, binding onChange on an option element is not valid and has not an effect.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault

Comment: <select class="btn dropdown-toggle" ONCHANGE="swapContent(this.value);">

<option>Kategorija</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>