# js change select name based on option selection

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dynamic drop down menu where options are loaded from database, Now i need to change the  attribute every time different option is selected from the drop down menu.

To achieve this I am trying to use js in my opinion suitable to do the job but unfortunately I find it difficult and cannot come up with a correct solution, actually i dont know how to start it.

Here is my PHP code that dynamicly generates drop down menu:

```
$opt = '<select id="Forex" name="" style="display: none">';
            $opt1 = '<option value="">Select Forex Workshop</option>';
                $opt2 = '';
                while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    if($timestamp < $result['endingDate']){
                    $opt2 .= '<option id="'.$result['id'].'" value="'.$result['startingDate'].'">'.$result['course'].'</option>';   
                    }
                }

                $opt3 =  '</select>';
                return $opt.$opt1.$opt2.$opt3;
```

Could some one suggest a solution a at least give me a link to a article that covers this problem

Comment: `document.getElementById('Forex').onchange = function() { this.name = this.value; }`

Comment: Why are you trying to change the attribute?

Comment: Doesn't that make it hard to process the input, if you don't know which name the parameter will have?

Comment: I need to change the name attribute because when i submit the form the correct infromation needs to be processed

Answer (score 2):

You can add "onchange" event and change the name whatever you like:

```
$('#Forex').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val(); // you can get the value of selected option

    //you can process your conditions here

    $(this).attr('name', 'your_choice_name'); // this will change the name attribute
});
```

or you can do this from javascript

```
<select id="Forex" name="abc" onchange="changeAttr(this);">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
function changeAttr(ele)
{
    var val = ele.value;
    var n = "";

    if(val == 1){
        n = 'xyz';
    } else if(val == 2){
        n = 'abc';
    }
    ele.setAttribute('name', n);
}
</script>
```

Hope this will help you what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery, with a "onChange" event that will change the attribute you want with the selected item in the list.

[jQuery get value of select onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange)

Answer (score 0):

Hei!
Not sure if I understood you, but you can use jQuery to manipulate attributes on change event.
For event http://api.jquery.com/change/
To change atribute http://api.jquery.com/attr/