# Javascript event for DropDownList value selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a DropDownList which has two options yes and no. I am using onchange event right now but it does not get fired the first time page is loaded with value yes in the dropdownlist.(since values has not been changed yet.) I want to set the visibility of controls depending on the current value of the dropdownlist.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAriba" onchange="ddlAribaChange(this);" runat="server"              ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="FormText" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Y" Selected='True'>Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="N">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**JAVACRIPT**

```
function ddlAribaChange(ddl) {
    var txtAribaDocumentNumber = document.getElementById("txtAribaDocumentNumber");
    var ddlAribaReason = document.getElementById("ddlAribaReason");
    //alert(ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text);
    if (ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text == 'Yes') {
        txtAribaDocumentNumber.style.display = 'inherit';
        ddlAribaReason.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        txtAribaDocumentNumber.style.display = 'none';
        ddlAribaReason.style.display = 'inherit';
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Comment: you need to check it when DOM is ready. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery you can achieve like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ddlAriba').change(function(){

    alert($(this).val());

    });

});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ddlAriba').on('change',function(){

        alert($(this).val());

        });

});
```

if its not firing this way, use delegated event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change','#ddlAriba',function(){

        alert($(this).val());

        });

});
```

Comment: I dont not want to do it onchange. Because this event does not get fired when the page first loads.

Comment: But how will it get fired without someone changing the selected value? 
By default the sected value of dropdown is the first value "Yes"

Comment: when you will change selected index it will fire you want to get first value as well which is default selected?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to page lifetime.
Maybe it will be better to display/hide your [select] using code-behind instead of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function when the `DOM` is ready

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ddlAribaChange($('#<%=ddlAriba.ClientID%>').val());
});
```

May be this will help you.

Or you can put the same code in `$(document).ready()` function as you want that behavior by default when the page is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var txtAribaDocumentNumber = document.getElementById("txtAribaDocumentNumber");
   var ddlAribaReason = document.getElementById("ddlAribaReason");
   var ddl = $('#<%=ddlAriba.ClientID%>');
   //alert(ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text);
   if (ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text == 'Yes') {
    txtAribaDocumentNumber.style.display = 'inherit';
    ddlAribaReason.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else {
    txtAribaDocumentNumber.style.display = 'none';
    ddlAribaReason.style.display = 'inherit';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to call `ddlAribaChange` when `DOM` is *ready* and pass the `ddlAriba` DOM object. As you have `ClientIDMode="static"` you do not need to access `ClientID` in javascript to get DOM object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ddlAribaChange(document.getElementById('ddlAriba'));
});
```