# ASP form if select option selected, change email address

Tags: jquery, forms, if-statement, asp-classic

I have a form that has a select box with several different options. I want the recipient's email address if the user selects a certain option.

Here is some kind of ASP pseudocode, I just need help grabbing the data from my form.  Do I need to use jQuery/JavaScript to do so, or is a different way?

```
<% 
Dim selectedoption
Dim specialoption

if selectedoption="specialoption" then #this would pull data from form
varrecipient = "ImSpecial@domain.com" #this would pull data from form

else

varrecipient = "NotSoSpecial@domain.com"

else if

varFormName = "ContactFormName"
varRHBusinessUnit = "Business1"
varLanguage = "ENGLISH"
varCourtesyResponse = "Y"
varRedirect = "#noredir?formRun=true"
varSubject = "Subject of my Form"
%>
```

FORM:

```
<form style="width: 530px;" method="post" name="contactFormName" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="hidden" name="Redirect" value="/thankyou.htm" />
<input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Subject of my form" />

<label>First Name<sup> &#8225;</sup></label>
<input name="sFName" type="text" size="40" value="<%= Server.HTMLEncode(Request.Form("sFName")) %>">

<label>Last Name<sup> &#8225;</sup></label>
<input name="sLName" type="text" size="40" value="<%= Server.HTMLEncode(Request.Form("sLName")) %>">

<label>Company/ Organization<sup> &#8225;</sup></label>
<input name="sCName" type="text" size="40" value="<%= Server.HTMLEncode(Request.Form("sCName")) %>" >

<label>Company Type<sup> &#8225;</sup></label>
    <select name="sCType">
        <option value="Brand">Brand</option>
        <option value="Retailer">Retailer</option>
        <option value="Converter">Converter</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>

<label>Email<sup> &#8225;</sup></label>
<input name="sEmail" type="text" size="40" value="<%= Server.HTMLEncode(Request.Form("sEmail")) %>" >

<input type="submit" class="fbutton" value="Send" />

</form>
```

Comment: Why are you giving us PseudoCode?, why not actually code ??. Using pseudocode you are letting pass important details ... only a comment.

Comment: Like I said in my post, I don't know the code, that's the whole question.

Comment: I would use jQuery possibly even ajax depending on how many different email addresses there are.  You can look here for a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Comment: @ControlFreak: The OP's having problems with Classic ASP - JavaScript is probably going to be the last thing on their mind at this point.

Comment: @Paul I really don't see why the OP would use server side code to produce client-side functionality. Well I do, but it's really not necessary.  jQuery isn't hard to use/learn, also, OP has `jQuery` tag in post.  This may be a good time to pick-up jQuery for the Op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the request object.  Eg If your SCtype select is what you want to use to determine the relevant recipient address then you could use this.

```
<%
If Request.Form("sCType") = "Brand" or Request.Form("sCType") = "Retailer" then
varrecipient = "ImSpecial@domain.com"
Else
varrecipient = "NotSoSpecial@domain.com"
End If
%>
```