# Issue on change jquery function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onchange

I am facing very weird issue. I have a dropdown option

```
<table class="variations">
   <tr>
      <td>
          <select name="up_options">
             <option value="" selected>Select Value</option>
             <option value="a">A</option>
             <option value="b">B</option>
             <option value="c">C</option>
             <option value="d">D</option>
             <option value="e">E</option>
          </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and make a jquery function that alerts me the selected value but it did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.variations select').change(function(){
           alert(jQuery('.single_variation').text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when i edit the `change` to `click` it works perfectly (perfectly means it works only on click) when i click on select it gives me alert ... But when i change again it to `change` its not work.

I also try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
        jQuery('.variations select').on('change', function(){
           alert(jQuery('.single_variation').text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it also not work.

Please help me i am very confuse about it

Comment: Theres nothing here that should not be working. Can you provide a working example of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: What is `.single_variation`?

Comment: Find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Comment: Adding an identifier to the select itself and binding the onchange to that works fine. Can't explain why though

Comment: @HuzoorBux OP wants to get the value of a different element, not the select, and besides what they have should work fine as it is.

Comment: @adeneo ".single_variation" is the place where i want to show the value

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5capd4sh/) The code you have works for me. is this possibly a browser issues/jquery bug? im on firefox 36 beta

Comment: Please show your *entire page* as something is missing from the puzzle here :)

Comment: Can you add a **jsfiddle** demo please ? What browser(s) are you using ? What is the code for `.single_variation` element ? Does this element can be updated by another part of your code ? What do you mean by `it did not work` ? What is the **exact behavior** you want, and what is the **exact behavior** you get ? Do you have another `change` event listerner elsewhere in your code ? Do this listener use either `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation` or `return false;` ? It looks like the source of your problem is not present in the code you've provided right now, so we need more info ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing "wrong" with the original code, but you can make the following improvements:

```
   // Shortcut for DOM ready with locally scoped $
   jQuery(function($) {

        // Delegated event handler attached to a common ancestor
        $('.variations').on('change','select',function(){

            // this is the select itself, so use its val()
           var currentSelectVal = $(this).val();

           // Do something with the selection
           $('.single_variation').text(currentSelectVal);
        });
    });
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/z9ev6rrp/2/

**Note:** *I look forward to seeing the rest of the page & code in order to determine where your actual problem lies :)*

Comment: thanx alot bro you save my life and my day ..... i make some changes in your code and its work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 jQuery('select[name="up_options"]').change(function(){
      jQuery('.single_variation').text( $(this).val());
      alert(jQuery('.single_variation').text());
  });
```

Comment: This should make no difference (aside from slowing the selector down a tad). The original code *should* work.

Comment: Also note: you switched to using `$` partway through. You have to be consistent with the OPs usage of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.variations select').change(function(){
        $(".single_variation").text((jQuery('.variations select option:selected').text()));    
        });
    });
```

OR

```
$(".single_variation").text($(this).val().toUpperCase());
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grfhocxg/)**

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I checked it it will return whole text

Comment: Sorry I meant: What's wrong with `jQuery(this).val()` :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is really good with **current element** as `$(this)` or `jQuery(this)`, so use like,

```
alert(jQuery(this).text()); // to alert the content of the selected item

alert(jQuery(this).val()); // to alert the value of the selected item
```

Comment: the issue is the change event not firing, not the alert

Answer (score 1):

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/58xzv6q7/)**

The event is getting fired and the result is being displayed according to the `select` option.

Comment: Please add any relevant changed code in your answer

Answer (score 1):

### You could try like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('body').on('change','.variations select[name="up_options"]',function(){
           alert(jQuery('.single_variation').text());
           alert(jQuery
(this).val()); //Current Drowndown value
        });
    });
```

**Binding events using delegate is appropriate and best practice.**

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/z9ev6rrp/1/)**

Comment: Binding delegated events to `body` is *not* recommended as it has a bug related to styling (it does not get some events if the computed height is 0 due to styling). Use `document` instead *as the default if nothing else is closer* (in your example using `jQuery('.variations').on('change','select', function(){` makes more sense and is more efficient.

Comment: Secondly, the original code works too, so the problem lays somewhere not yet discovered :)