# Dependent dropdown list using jquery cannot populate html file

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have two drop-down lists where the second depends on the first drop-down list selection.

I've tested *getSalary* and *getamount* and it can fetch the array but cannot be loaded to *try.php*.
What could have gone wrong? Here are my codes.

**try.php:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
Grade and Increment
<select name="salaryid"  id="salaryid" ></select>
<br>  

Salary Amount:
<select name="salaryamt"  id="salaryamt" ></select>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("getSalary.php", success = function(data) {
        var options = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            options += "<options value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</options>";
        }

        $("#salaryid").append(options);
        $("#salaryid").change();

    });

    $("#salaryid").change(function(){
        $.getJSON("getAmount.php?make=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data) {
            var options = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options += "<options value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</options>";
            }
            $("#salaryamt").html("");
            $("#salaryamt").append(options);
        });
    });
});
```

**getSalary.php**

```
<?php
include 'pmis_conn.php';

$qrysal = mysql_query("Select grade_incre from salary_ref where year = '2012'") or die(mysql_error());

$makes = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qrysal))
{
    array_push($makes, $row['grade_incre']);
}
echo json_encode($makes);
?>
```

**getamount.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["make"])) {
    include 'pmis_conn.php';

    $make = $_GET["make"];

    $qrysal = mysql_query("Select amount, year from salary_ref where grade_incre like '{$make}'") or die(mysql_error());

    $amount = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qrysal))
    {
        //$amt = $row['amount'] + "-" + $row['year']
        array_push($amount, $row['amount']);
    }
    echo json_encode($amount);

}
?>
```

Comment: In the GET you call *getAmount.php* but in the file name you put getamount.php just a typo?

Comment: i've changed it but it still has the same output. Both blank select boxes.

Comment: But what's the correct filename? did you try the first point i suggested you? what's the devtools say?

Comment: getamount.php. i've got this from the scope local, <return>: undefined this: document

Comment: now i've loaded the salaryid thru mysql and tried the onchange and alerted the value. How can I connect value with the salaryamt now?

Comment: what do you mean with this "How can I connect value with the salaryamt now?"

Comment: Meaning if I select from from the first dropdown which is salaryid, I should be able to load the salary amount from my database to the second dropdown which is salaryamt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following things:

1. the GET php calls are executed as expected
2. the javascript is triggered as expected

**Debug the GET calls:**

For debugging try to use in Chrome the *Developer tools* `Ctrl+shift+I`.
In there check the *Network* tab to see what's going on with your ajax call.

Here the manual: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
here a tutorial: http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/

**Debug the javascript:**

Alvways from the  *Developer tools* go on *Source* and put some break points on *script.js*.

Here the manual for debug js: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

**Additional issue in the javascript:**

As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/86vjfwLe/3/ your `$(this).val()` is null.
You should try this method instead : [jQuery get value of select onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange) .

**Additional issues with the html and on change:**
The html you are injecting  is broken. You have to replace `options` to `option`and it should work.