# Take current option in onChange() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the way to take the option that the user just clicked using "onChange" event?
What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
<select name="my_select" onchange="checkOption(this)">
    <option value="first">1</option>
    <option value="second">2</option>
    <option value="third">3</option>
</select>
```

And the function:

```
function checkOption(e) {
    if ( jQuery(e).val() == 'second' )
        alert('You just clicked the second option!')
}
```

However I have no idea how to access the "this" represents the current option.

I know how to do this using the jquery `change()` event, however in my specific case this option isn't good.
Any help will be appreciate!

Edit: This isn't duplication since the question there is about how to use jquery's `change()` event, which as I said is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Why not have a `$([name='my_select']).on('change', funciton(){ cur_val = $('option:selected', this).val(); })`. If you are using jQuery, try to avoid events on view.

Comment: @Rajesh or just `$(this).val()` :)

Comment: May it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31a0q06r/#&togetherjs=CvsLo7o8s9)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of select onChange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange)

Comment: What does *However I have no idea how to access the "this" represents the current option.* mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid using jquery all together, you can try the following...

```js
function checkOption(e) {
  if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value === 'second')
        alert('You just clicked the second option!')
}
```

```html
<select name="my_select" onchange="checkOption(this)">
    <option value="first">1</option>
    <option value="second">2</option>
    <option value="third">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Mackan - There is no point. Thanks for the heads up. I have cleaned up the answer and removed the lines that are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's inbuilt onchange function something like below:

```
    <select name="my_select" class="my_select">
        <option value="first">1</option>
        <option value="second">2</option>
        <option value="third">3</option>
    </select>
```

Solution :

```
<script>
$(".my_select").change(function(){
  //every time you change value this will automatically calls
  if( this.value == 'second'){
    alert('You just clicked the second option!');
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$("my_select")` won't bind to that HTML element. Thats looking for something like `<my_select>`...

Comment: Fix the event too then: `change()`

Answer (score 0):

Without JQuery you can use plain javascript like the below one to access the selected values

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("my_select")[0];
var selectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if ( selectedText == 'second' )
    alert('You just clicked the second option!')
```

Answer (score -1):

put an id in the html code and remove this keyword as:

```
<select id="id" name="my_select" onchange="checkOption()">
    <option value="first">1</option>
    <option value="second">2</option>
    <option value="third">3</option>
</select>
```

Then edit java script function as:

```
function checkOption() {
  var text = document.getElementById('id').value

    if ( text == 'second' )
        alert('You just clicked the second option!')
}
```

Hope it works!