# HTML get name of select option

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to get `name` of the select option, but it appears to be blank, demonstrated in codepen. Getting `value` works though, so I want to get `name` in the same manner.

As you can see, `name` is different for each option so it cannot be added in the `<select>`, and I want to avoid using `data-` as it would require hard-coding this edge case into re-usable functions.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJzQWW?editors=1010

```
<select>
  <option name="" value="" selected>Or</option>
  <option name="tags" value="123">And</option>
  <option name="not-tags" value="123">Not</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is probably going to confuse the hell out of your html form. `option`s typically dont have "name" components. Can you explain what you're trying to do by using `name` on an `option`?

Comment: @haxxxton backend parses `name` by splitting at `-` characters and reading each component. If the first component is `not`, then it does a SQL `NOT` query, etc. There are other similar modifiers for querying, this is just one example.

Comment: Can you take advantage of the `value` attribute? or you need that for something else? Alternatively, if you _must_ use `name`, you may need a js solution that creates a `hidden` input with the `name` dynamically created for what you're after, as your current solution is going to cause you strife IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(input).find(":selected") will get you the selected option, from there you can use val() and attr() to get the values

```
    function parseInputs(jqElem, selector = ':input', payload = '') {
      for (let input of $(jqElem).find(selector)) {
        const value = $(input).find(":selected").val();
        const name = $(input).find(":selected").attr("name");
        if (!value) {
          continue
        }
        payload += `&${name}=${value}`;
      }
      return payload.substring(1);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. This will still require some hard-coding into the reusable function, but it's probably the best I'll get with the current spec. One question: Why do you use `const`? I tried it with `let` and it seems to work, but is there a reason not to use it?

Comment: You could use "let", "var" or "const", all will work. But seeing as the value and name probably won't change within that scope, setting them as constants is the best approach, both technically and "humanly".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have a confusion. [The tag `option` doesn't have a name attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp). The name attribute can exist in the `select` tag.

If you want to know which option has been selected, you have to listen the `change` event for the `select` element and take the `value`attribue. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange).

Or maybe you can try whit something like [dataset](http://html5demos.com/dataset), but you have to always listen the `change` event.

Comment: Okey. Sorry about that. But it's a weird question. Look in the [oficial spec](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option). Option doesn't have a name attribute. One of the correct ways if you want to do something like that its to use dataset.

Comment: Yes I know, that's what I said in my question to avoid using `data-` and I said why. Event listeners seems excessive for this. You've nothing to apologize for. But the three voters who thought this deserved more attention than the other two answers that have actual working solutions need to have their brains checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a VERY weird question, but I won't bitch about that.
Here's how you do it the kickass way:

```
function parseInputs(jqElem, selector = ':input', payload = '') {
  payload ="";
  $(jqElem).find(selector).each(function () {
      input = $(this);
      payload += "&"
                + $(this).find("option[value=\"" + input.val() + "\"]").attr("name") //just a heads up, if there is more than one with the same value, this won't work...
                + "=" + 
                input.val();
  });
  return payload;
}

$('#asdf').on('click', () => {
  console.log(parseInputs('#wtf'));
});
```

Comment: That worked. I'm not sure if it's the best solution (still reading through the logic) and I'm not sure why someone downvoted you without commenting, but it deserves at least a vote because it works.

Comment: I don't think it is the best solution either, but this functionality really isn't existent in native HTML.  Sorry, mate; I hope you get a better solution.