# Change event not working in a boostrap multiple select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML page contains a bootstrap multiple select field:

```
<select class="form-control bootstrap-select"
    data-style="alpha-grey-300 pt-5 pb-5 pl-10 text-size-mini" multiple
    id="associated.persons"
    data-live-search="true">
</select>
```

Every time a new set of selection is made, the jQuery change event is not working. When I write this code,

```
$('#associated.persons').change(function (e) {
        console.log("Input changed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    });
```

Nothing is written it the console. I don't know where the problem is exactly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't used a point in your id or class name. 
Actually combine hashtag and point in the same rules says your selector search a bloc with id "**associated**" and class "**persons**".

Rename your ID and never used the point in your ID or class name. Used  - or _ if your want create an ID or class name with multiple words.

You can doing this:

```
<select class="form-control bootstrap-select"
    data-style="alpha-grey-300 pt-5 pb-5 pl-10 text-size-mini" multiple
    id="associated-persons"
    data-live-search="true">
</select>
```

And

```
$('#associated-persons').change(function (e) {
        console.log("Input changed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id="associated.persons"
```

Here is the problem. Use another selector and it will work. 
In your code jquery will try to bind onChange to item with class 'person' and with id="associated"