# Javascript onchange not changing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, pickadate

I am using a library called pickadate/pickatime. http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/

here is the code:

```
<select id="day" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="[7,30]">Day 1</option>
    <option value="[8,00]">Day 2</option>
    <option value="[10,20]">Day 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="time">

<script>
var value = document.getElementById('day').value;
function myFunction() {
    $('#time').pickatime( {
        min: value // minimum time
    });
}
</script>
```

let me explain what the code does.

every time the `select` changes, the onchange myFunction() should fire. it does on the first time. that's the problem. If I first select day 2, it will insert the min value `[8,00]` in the javascript function.

if i DO NOT refresh the page and select day 1 or day 3 after i have already selected something, it will not update the min value. how can i fix this?

EDIT: The problem: i'm initializing $('#time').pickatime... the first time. how can i reinitialize it or refresh it?

Comment: Replaced your functions body with a console.log(), gets called every time the select changes. Seems to be a problem with your pickatime method. https://jsfiddle.net/nosh9Lwu/

Comment: @Ken Yes, the problem is i'm initializing $('#time').pickatime, i cannot reinitialize it or refresh it?

Comment: Since you are already using JQuery, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange) might help

Comment: What is pickatime?

Comment: how about $(document).on("change",'#day',function(){ ... });

Comment: @Ken its a function

Comment: ...Obviously, but you didnt include it in your code snippet and it doesnt appear to be part of jQuery or JS.

Comment: @gaheinrichs i think its the initializing of the `pickatime`. i need to refresh it or reinitialize it

Comment: @ken its a library. i have a link in the op. it is definitely working the first onchange. it does not work afterwards...

Comment: @silverfighter i think its the initializing of the `pickatime`. i need to refresh it or reinitialize it

Comment: Use the plugin documented events

Comment: @charlietfl where? i cant seem to find it?

Comment: Look at `events` in docs you linked to

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#time').pickatime();
var element = document.getElementById('day');
function myFunction() {
    $('#time').pickatime( {
        min: element.value // minimum time
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear time input value. Try like below;

```
 $('input[type="time"]').val(null);
```