# Something causing page reload via javascript on click of select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

An example url is located here:  [link removed]

The code I have in place is simply this:

```
$('.jump-submit').on('change', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('form').submit();
});
```

But if you click on the select box to choose a state, before you can choose a state, the form seems to be submitted anyways as if it's being triggered by an `click` event, when I'm using the `change` event.

Not very good at debugging this in the console, but have "Preserve Log enabled and also put a checkbox in "Load -> unload" in the Sources tab of Chrome, but stepping through it with "Pause on Exceptions" points to `DOM Exception Failed to execute 'queryselectorall'` but than researching this says to not use "Pause on Exceptions" in chrome and that this is not a jQuery bug.

How to debug this properly and determine what is causing the page to refresh before the change event should be happening on this Select box?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179432/2311317

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a class called `submit-form` on the dropdown and you have the following click event causing the behavior:

```
...).on('click', '.submit-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

It's line 175 of app.js (after prettifying, might differ in the source)

Comment: But wait, `.jump-submit` is not the same as `.submit-form`.  They are 2 different elements.  Does jQuery not understand this?

Comment: `.jump-submit` is a child of `.submit-form`.  You have a `change` event for the dropdown and a `click` event for the form itself.  They both submit the form.  I don't see why you would ever want to submit the form anytime you click on it.  My assumption is you meant to add the `.submit-form` to a button and not the form itself?

Comment: Wait, I see what's happening.  .submit-form is the parent, and therefore getting the click event fired.  Thanks :)

Comment: Oh yes, I misunderstood.  Clicking on the dropdown also fires the click event of the parent due to event bubbling.

Comment: Hmm... not sure why but `event.preventDefault();` was also needed for a JQuery multi-select option element in a form in order for the page to not refresh when I programatically selected all options.

Comment: @THEJOATMON hi there, the same thing happening to me, whatever input type i click on, it trigger automatic page reload & i tried event.preventDefault(); but that's not working. pls help.