# Change the div of select B when select A changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of selects and want to change the class on the second select tag when the first select tag has an option selected. (I am using Semantic UI.)

**HTML:**

```
<select id="grade" name="grade" class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="">Grade</option>
  <option value="kinder">Kindergarten</option>
  <option value="g1">Grade 1</option>
  <option value="g2">Grade 2</option>
  <option value="g3">Grade 3</option>
  <option value="g4">Grade 4</option>
  <option value="g5">Grade 5</option>
  <option value="g6">Grade 6</option>
  <option value="g7">Grade 7</option>
  <option value="g8">Grade 8</option>
  <option value="g9">Grade 9</option>
  <option value="g10">Grade 10</option>
  <option value="g11">Grade 11</option>
  <option value="g12">Grade 12</option>
</select>

<select id="subject" name="subject" class="ui disabled dropdown">
  <option value="">Subject</option>
  <option value="kinder-esl" class="kinder">ESL</option>
  <option value="kinder-la" class="kinder">LA</option>
  <option value="kinder-health" class="kinder">Health</option>
  <option value="kinder-ict" class="kinder">ICT</option>
  <option value="kinder-math" class="kinder">Math</option>
  <option value="kinder-pe" class="kinder">PE</option>
  <option value="kinder-primary-grades" class="kinder">Primary Grades</option>
  <option value="kinder-science" class="kinder">Science</option>
  <option value="kinder-social-studies" class="kinder">Social Studies</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#grade').change(function(){
    $('#subject').removeClass('ui disabled dropdown').addClass('ui dropdown');
  });
});
```

Here's my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/95p2u8er/

When selecting an option from the 'grade' select tag, the 'subject' select tag is staying disabled. How can I modify my JS to switch the class on the 'subject' select so that it is '**ui dropdown**'?

Comment: You forgot to add `jQuery` in your jsfiddle, it works better with it. Remove part can be simplified to `$('#subject').removeClass('disabled');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle didn't include a reference to JQuery.

But, you also have to consider what happens if the first select has a choice (other than Grade) chosen, which will activate the second drop down, **but then the first drop down is put back at Grade. That should re-disable the second list.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#grade').change(function(){
    // Depending on whether the first select has a valid value
    // either enable the second list or not. It's important to
    // have the else portion because someone could activate the
    // second list and then change the first list back to "Grade"
    // Also, you don't need to be adding back the "dropdown" class
    // because the elements are always dropdowns. You only need to 
    // worry about the "disabled" class
    if(this.value){
      $('#subject').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $('#subject').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.min.css">

<select id="grade" name="grade" class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="">Grade</option>
  <option value="kinder">Kindergarten</option>
  <option value="g1">Grade 1</option>
  <option value="g2">Grade 2</option>
  <option value="g3">Grade 3</option>
  <option value="g4">Grade 4</option>
  <option value="g5">Grade 5</option>
  <option value="g6">Grade 6</option>
  <option value="g7">Grade 7</option>
  <option value="g8">Grade 8</option>
  <option value="g9">Grade 9</option>
  <option value="g10">Grade 10</option>
  <option value="g11">Grade 11</option>
  <option value="g12">Grade 12</option>
</select>

<select id="subject" name="subject" class="ui disabled dropdown">
  <option value="">Subject</option>
  <option value="kinder-esl" class="kinder">ESL</option>
  <option value="kinder-la" class="kinder">LA</option>
  <option value="kinder-health" class="kinder">Health</option>
  <option value="kinder-ict" class="kinder">ICT</option>
  <option value="kinder-math" class="kinder">Math</option>
  <option value="kinder-pe" class="kinder">PE</option>
  <option value="kinder-primary-grades" class="kinder">Primary Grades</option>
  <option value="kinder-science" class="kinder">Science</option>
  <option value="kinder-social-studies" class="kinder">Social Studies</option>
</select>
```

Also, in the future, please post your code examples right here in Stack Overflow (in a "code snippet" available from the new question toolbar) rather than at a 3rd party location as those links can become broken over time.

Comment: Now your second `select` has two `id` tags.

Comment: @mx0 Updated answer.

Comment: Holy crap, I can't believe I overlooked that. Wait, yes I can... Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your JS works as written, but you have to enable jQuery in the fiddle. 
Click the gear icon in the JS panel and select a flavor of jQuery to make it work.

That said, why are you removing all of the classes just to add two back in. you can simply do the following:

```
$('#subject').removeClass('disabled');
```

That will just remove the class specified and leave the others

Comment: Thanks for adding something useful that I can append to the answer provided by Scott Marcus

Comment: Also you could potentially add onchange listener directly to first select element.. But that's a style preference. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179421/495157

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function.

```
$('#grade').on("change", function(){
    $('#subject').toggleClass('disabled', $(this).val() === '');
 });
```

Also, your jsfiddle doesn't have jQuery enabled, maybe that's why ?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated your fiddle to include jquery, and this worked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("ready called");
  $('#grade').change(function(){
    alert("click called");
    $('#subject').removeClass('disabled');
  });
});
```