# JS won't load into html

Tags: javascript, html

might be a silly question but im really stuck..Nothing is happening with this code. It's like the js isnt attached properly? Not sure why

add.js

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
})
```

html:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="add.js"></script>
</head>

<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Provide full html. It is important where you do write your js and where you do load jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get value of select onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

`./index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/add.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

And `./js/add.js`

```
$(function(){
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you provide a relative path, the browser will be looking for your file in the folder relative to the current URL. For example, if your url is http://localhost/some/path and you include script like the following.

```
<script src="js/add.js" ></script>
```

The browser will look for your file at http://localhost/some/path/js/add.js

If you want the browser to always look for your file in js folder at the root directory, you can specify an absolute path.

```
<script src="/js/add.js" ></script>
```

Now the browser will always look for your file at http://localhost/js/add.js regardless of what your current URL is.