# Jquery keyup triggered after both numbers

Tags: jquery, keyup

```
$(".maxQtyclass").keyup(function () { 
    var maxQty = $(this).attr('data-qty');
    //lets say it is 8
    if ($(this).val() > maxQty
        && e.keyCode != 46 // delete
        && e.keyCode != 8 // backspace
    ) { 
        $(this).val(maxQty);
        alert('Only ' + maxQty + ' unit(s) available!');
        return false; 
    } 
});
```

When I press 8 (no message since 8 is not > than 8.) When I press 9 it triggers alert that only 8 units available. So far so good but when I press 12 it does not trigger alert, why? 12 is > than 8. Looks like keyup reads only first number entered. How to do force keyup to read number 12?

Comment: you can use change event to get the whole string and check it...

Comment: Never use keyup to compare values. It always considers the previous value. Instead use blur or change event.

Comment: This shows how to use onchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event object in the function to get keycode

```js
$(".maxQtyclass").keyup(function (e) { 
        var maxQty = $(this).attr('data-qty');
        //lets say it is 8\
        if (parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt(maxQty)
            && e.keyCode != 46 // delete
            && e.keyCode != 8 // backspace
            ) { 
                $(this).val(maxQty);
                console.log('Only ' + maxQty + ' unit(s) available!');
                return false; 
            } 
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="maxQtyclass" data-qty="8"/>
```

Comment: yep. That is what I asked for. You guys THE best!

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is doing the string comparison so "12" > "8" is failing. Try converting to int and compare as below.

```
$(".maxQtyclass").keyup(function () { 
        var maxQty = $(this).attr('data-qty');
        //lets say it is 8
        if (parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt(maxQty)
            && e.keyCode != 46 // delete
            && e.keyCode != 8 // backspace
            ) { 
            $(this).val(maxQty);
            alert('Only ' + maxQty + ' unit(s) available!');
            return false; 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Works. I should have asked it earlier. Would save me 3 hours in research.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your input text to number. In your scenario you compare "12" > "8" in string data type, and because 12 start with 1 and 1 in string is less than 8 the condition returns false. Change the code like this:

```
$(".maxQtyclass").keyup(function () { 
    var maxQty = parseInt($(this).attr('data-qty'));
    //lets say it is 8
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) > maxQty
        && e.keyCode != 46 // delete
        && e.keyCode != 8 // backspace
    ) { 
        $(this).val(maxQty);
        alert('Only ' + maxQty + ' unit(s) available!');
        return false; 
    } 
});
```

Be sure all numbers are int.