# onClick function isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a drop down menu, I want to show a div having another drop down menu when I select an option in first drop down.

For this, I have used `onClick` function on every option tag. Every option has a different div. the problem is; It isn't showing me the div when I select an option.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="first">

  <option selected; value="" disabled="disabled">Select an Option</option> 

  <option value="all">Select All</option>   
  <option value="Sno">Sno</option>
  <option value="name" onclick="showMe('namediv',this)" onclick="ckChnage(this)">Name</option>
  <option value="course" onclick="showMe('coursediv',this)" >Mauza</option>
  </select>
  <div id="namediv" style="display: none";>
    <select name="firstres" id="firstres"><option style="display:none;" selected; value="">---Select an option---</option>
<?php 
   $sql="SELECT * FROM table ";     
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
      echo "<option  value=' " . $row['Sno'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
   }
?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `onclick="showMe('namediv',this)" onclick="ckChnage(this)"` -- why there are two click bindings?

Comment: It's onClick.. I want to show a div when i click or select one of the option. In that div, there is another drop down menu that I want to show.

Comment: No, I was just trying the another one

Comment: He doesn't know much about onChange but it seems like he's trying his best to learn.

Comment: @DevJ see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick` does not work on `option` tag, you might want to use `onchange` event on `select` tag

**Edit:** Since you wish to hide all other `div`s, you can first hide all `div`, then display the selected `div`

```js
function showMe(element){
  if ( element.value==='all' ) {
    document.getElementById( 'Snodiv'    ).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById( 'namediv'   ).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById( 'coursediv' ).style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById( 'Snodiv'    ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( 'namediv'   ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( 'coursediv' ).style.display = 'none';
    
    var div = document.getElementById( element.value + "div" );
  
    if ( div ) {
      div.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="first" onchange="showMe(this)">

  <option selected value="" disabled="disabled">
    Select an Option
  </option> 
  <option value="all">Select All</option>   
  <option value="Sno">Sno</option>
  <option value="name">Name</option>
  <option value="course">Mauza</option>
</select>

<div id="Snodiv" style="display: none";>
    Sno
    <select name="firstres" id="firstres">
      <option selected value="">
        ---Select an option---
      </option>
      <option value="some-option">Some option</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="namediv" style="display: none";>
    Name
    <select name="firstres" id="firstres">
      <option selected value="">
        ---Select an option---
      </option>
      <option value="some-option">Some option</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="coursediv" style="display: none";>
    Mauza
    <select name="firstres" id="firstres">
      <option selected value="">
        ---Select an option---
      </option>
      <option value="some-option">Some option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That's working. Can u please help me with one more thing? I want to hide all the other divs and only show the one whose option is selected. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

for selecet you have to use `onchang`
Here you can learn about it:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
       if(x == "course"){
        document.getElementById('coursediv').style.display="block";
    } 
}
```

```html
<select name="first" onchange="myFunction()" id="select">

  <option selected; value="" disabled="disabled">Select an Option</option> 

  <option value="all">Select All</option>   
  <option value="Sno">Sno</option>
  <option value="name">Name</option>
  <option value="course">Mauza</option>
  </select>
<div id="coursediv" style="display:none">I am coursediv dive</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: And where do I include my div

Comment: after it and create another function for it and set `ochange` to the `select` tag

Comment: so where? I show you how to get the value do whatever you want with the value

Comment: Just give me the idea to make a div onchange. I have no idea how to do it :(

Comment: but i got the idea. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: mybe the issue in php code ... because div was shown onclick

Comment: by the way I really appricate if you up vote/mark as answer

Comment: Can u help me with one more thing? I want to hide all the divs which are not selected and only show the one which is selected

Comment: Can u please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265884/cant-replace-drop-downs-using-onchange-function?noredirect=1#comment87550194_50265884

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve what you want using onclick as you have a drop-down element.

You need to use onChange not onClick since you need to check when the "drop-down" was "changed".

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange) for further reading about onChange.

You need to change your code to this:

```
<select name="first" id="first_select">
  <option value="" selected>Select an Option</option> 
  <option value="all">Select All</option>   
  <option value="Sno">Sno</option>
  <option value="name">Name</option>
  <option value="course">Mauza</option>
</select>
```

I added an ID as a reference for the script. You can implement this in many ways I just prefer it this way.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#first_select").change(function(){
        if(this.value == "course"){
            showMe('coursediv',this);
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

We check when your first drop-down element is changed and when it does we trigger your `showMe` function. In my answer, I checked first if the selected element is "course" and if it is then we show the "coursediv". You can add your other option there as well to display what you need it to display.