# Can't replace drop downs using onChange function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two drop down menus, I want to show a div having the second drop down when i select a value from first drop down, for this I used onChange function and it's working fine. But i want to show a default drop down having no value when I have not selected anything from first one and when I select something from first one it replaces that default empty drop down with that div showing the second drop down having values. I don't know how to replace it. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showMe(element){
  if ( element.value==='all' ) {
    document.getElementById( 'namediv'    ).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById( 'coursediv'   ).style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    document.getElementById( 'namediv'    ).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( 'coursediv'   ).style.display = 'none';

    var div = document.getElementById( element.value + "div" );

    if ( div ) {
      div.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<select name="first" onchange="showMe(this)">
  <option selected value="" disabled="disabled">Select an Option</option> 
  <option value="all">Select All</option>   
  <option value="name" >Name</option>
  <option value="course" >Courses</option>
 </select>

 <select><option style="display:none;" selected; value="">---Select an option---</option></select> //default empty drop down

<div id="namediv" style="display: none";>
    <select name="firstres" id="firstres"><option style="display:none;" selected; value="">---Select an option---</option><?php 
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<option  value=' " . $row['Sno'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
    }
?>
    </select>
</div> //div which i wan't to show when i select a value from first drop down, and replaces the empty drop down
```

Comment: use `onSelect()`

Comment: This `selected;` doesn't need `;`

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace and from where?

Comment: I want to replace the drop down menu having no options (I haven't given any id to it) with the div having id namediv , when I select any value from the first drop down menu

Comment: Please check the following... would give you an idea how to reach you goal: ˋ element.options[element.selectedIndex].value ˋ if you want to get the value of the selected option and build your if statement based on it.