# How can I get data-att from select tag after user select an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group ">
   <select class="form-control input-sm col-xs-2 game-select" data-game="LuckyTuesday">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Game </option>

        <option id="1" data-name="Direct 1" data-minNumber="1" data-maxNumber="1">
            Direct 1
        </option>
        <option id="2" data-name="Direct 2" data-minNumber="2" data-maxNumber="2">
            Direct 2
        </option>
   </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    let gameType = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-name');

    //How to can I use "game-select" class to get "data-game" att? 
});
```

Comment: You know how to get the value of the option, isn't it the same for the `select` itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery get value of select onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange)

Comment: @naeramarth7 The question isn't about the value, it's about a `data-XXX` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of `data-game` simply by using the `data()` jQuery function:

```
$(this).data('game');
```