# Redirect to a page depending on option select when button is clicked with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a form that checks which option in `<select>` element is selected and then redirect to a page after button is clicked.

I've tried from [jQuery get value of select onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange), but it only helps when option is selected immediately.

```js
function getval() {
  if (sel.value == "2") {
    window.location.href = "payment1.html";
  } else if (sel.value == "3") {
    window.location.href = "payment2.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="payment-select">
  <option value="1">Select payment option</option>
  <option value="2">Payment1</option>
  <option value="3">Payment2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="getval()" class="button" value="Continue">
```

How would I connect this script to my `<input type="button" onclick="getval()" class="button" value="Continue">`?

Comment: `function getval() {
  let loc = ["","","payment1.html","payment2.html"][document.getElementById("payment-select").value]; if (loc) location.href=loc;
}` - sel is undefined

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sel` variable is `undefined`. You need to store the value of the selected option.
You can select it like this: `document.getElementById('payment-select')`.

```js
function getval() {
  var sel = document.getElementById('payment-select');

  if (sel.value == "2") {
    window.location.href = "payment1.html";
  } else if (sel.value == "3") {
    window.location.href = "payment2.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="payment-select">
  <option value="1">Select payment option</option>
  <option value="2">Payment1</option>
  <option value="3">Payment2</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="getval()" class="button" value="Continue">
```

Comment: @Quazey1389 Likely not. Anyway, feel free to delete this question since it is not useful for anyone but you

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't know SO works like this.

Comment: @Azametzin It does. It is a useless question for anyone but OP. SO tries to be a repository of solutions. Forgetting to get the value of an element is not worth saving

Comment: I see. On second thought, I could have used just the comments to answer it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And voted to close

Comment: Also I recommend using document.getElementById on IDs since it is faster and more logical