# Select only one unique option in a precedence from 3 repeated select tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three `Select` tags as follows

```
<select id='select1'>
<option value='1'> Option 1</option>
<option value='2'> Option 2</option>
<option value='3'> Option 3</option>
<option value='4'> Option 4</option>
</select>
----------------------------------------------
<select id='select2'>
<option value='1'> Option 1</option>
<option value='2'> Option 2</option>
<option value='3'> Option 3</option>
<option value='4'> Option 4</option>
</select>
-----------------------------------------------
<select id='select3'>
<option value='1'> Option 1</option>
<option value='2'> Option 2</option>
<option value='3'> Option 3</option>
<option value='4'> Option 4</option>
</select>
```

All the **Select** tags are same, except that they have different `id`. Now, a user needs to select one from each **Select** tag. However, the user must select unique value from each section.

**Example :-**

If the user selects **Option 2** in Section 1, s/he ***cannot*** select **that** option in Section 2 or 3.

Based on this, must I write **6** different cases in the Script file  ? Or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66291799/10606400)

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id='select1' onchange='checkUnique(this.value, this.id)'>
<option value=''> -Select One- </option>
<option value='1'> Option 1</option>
<option value='2'> Option 2</option>
<option value='3'> Option 3</option>
<option value='4'> Option 4</option>
</select>
----------------------------------------------
<select id='select2' onchange='checkUnique(this.value, this.id)'>
<option value=''> -Select One- </option>
<option value='1'> Option 1</option>
<option value='2'> Option 2</option>
<option value='3'> Option 3</option>
<option value='4'> Option 4</option>
</select>
-----------------------------------------------
<select id='select3' onchange='checkUnique(this.value, this.id)'>
<option value=''> -Select One- </option>
<option value='1'> Option 1</option>
<option value='2'> Option 2</option>
<option value='3'> Option 3</option>
<option value='4'> Option 4</option>
</select>

<script>
    function checkUnique(value, id) {
        let select1 = document.getElementById("select1").value
        let select2 = document.getElementById("select2").value
        let select3 = document.getElementById("select3").value
       
        if(id == "select1" && (value == select2 || value == select3) ){
             alert("already selected in other option");
             document.getElementById("select1").selectedIndex = 0;
             return false;
        }
        else if(id == "select2" && (value == select1 || value == select3) ){
             alert("already selected in other option");
             document.getElementById("select2").selectedIndex = 0;
             return false;
        }
        else if(id == "select3" && (value == select2 || value == select1) ){
             alert("already selected in other option");
             document.getElementById("select3").selectedIndex = 0;
             return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```