# How to hide dropdown option if it is not available?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have three dropdowns. Suppose there is the combination of "M / Grey" but not "M / Red" in the `name="id"` dropdown. If I select "M" in the first `.variant` dropdown the "Red" option should not be shown in the second `.variant` dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.variant').change(function(){    
 var options = $(this).find('.variant').children(":selected").get().map(function(el) {
  return el.value
 }).join(" / ");
 $('select[name="id"] option:contains(' + options + ')').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <select class="variant">
   <option value="S">S</option>
   <option value="M">M</option>
   <option value="L">L</option>
  </select>
  <select class="variant">
   <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
   <option value="Red">Red</option>
   <option value="White">White</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name="id">
   <option value="M / Grey">M / Grey</option>
   <option value="L / Grey">L / Grey</option>
   <option value="S / Red">S / Red</option>
   <option value="L / Red">L / Red</option>
   <option value="M / White">M / White</option>
   <option value="L / White">L / White</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: from which drop down you are selecting M and in which drop down you want to remove RED.

Comment: First drop down have S, M, L and second dropdown have Red, Grey, White.

Comment: and both 1st and 2nd drop down have variant class.

Comment: HI, you need to check that only on page load  and hide option where there is no match?

Comment: @Swati This is false. For example you can't hide "Red" just because there is no combination with "M". Then "Red" would also be hidden for "L" although the combination "L / Red" exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** You should add to each select a placeholder like an empty `option`. Otherwise you couldn't trigger the `change` event if you select a preselected value (here `S` and  `Grey`).

---

To update the other `select.variant` you have to compare its values (combined with the chosen value) with the values of the `select[name="id"]`.

You could achieve this with multiple solutions, for example data-attributes, the value strings or classes. I used classes for the following solution.

```html
<option class="m grey" value="M / Grey">M / Grey</option>
```

So you can simply check if there is an option that has the questionable class.

```js
if (!$('option').is('.' + val + '.' + color_val)) {...}
```

At the beginning of the `change` handler you have to "reset" the options of the other `select.variant` (remove all disabled attributes).

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.variant').change(function() {
    const val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    const variant_type = this.className.replace('variant', '').trim();
    
    $('.variant:not(.' + variant_type + ') option').attr('disabled', false);
    $('.variant:not(.' + variant_type + ') option').each(function() {
      const other_val = this.value.toLowerCase();

      if (!$('option').is('.' + other_val + '.' + val)) {
        this.disabled = true;
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <select class="variant size">
    <option></option>
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
  </select>
  <select class="variant color">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name="id">
    <option></option>
    <option class="m grey" value="M / Grey">M / Grey</option>
    <option class="l grey" value="L / Grey">L / Grey</option>
    <option class="s red" value="S / Red">S / Red</option>
    <option class="l red" value="L / Red">L / Red</option>
    <option class="m white" value="M / White">M / White</option>
    <option class="l white" value="L / White">L / White</option>
    <option class="xl red" value="XL / Red">XL / Red</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

---

If you want to use data-attributes you have to modify the function a slightly bit. The `select.variant` get instead of an additional class a `data-type` attribute. For example:

```html
<select class="variant" data-type="size">
```

**Combined example:** (*data-attributes and classes*)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.variant').change(function() {
    const val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    const variant_type = this.dataset.type;

    $('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"]) option').attr('disabled', false);
    $('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"]) option').each(function() {
      const other_val = this.value.toLowerCase();

      if (!$('option').is('.' + other_val + '.' + val)) {
        this.disabled = true;
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <select class="variant" data-type="size">
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
  </select>
  <select class="variant" data-type="color">
    <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name="id">
    <option class="m grey" value="M / Grey">M / Grey</option>
    <option class="l grey" value="L / Grey">L / Grey</option>
    <option class="s red" value="S / Red">S / Red</option>
    <option class="l red" value="L / Red">L / Red</option>
    <option class="m white" value="M / White">M / White</option>
    <option class="l white" value="L / White">L / White</option>
    <option class="xl red" value="XL / Red">XL / Red</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

---

For a solution with `data-attributes` only the `select[name="id"]` gets instead of two classes two data-attributes, one for each possible `data-type`-value - in this example: `data-size` and `data-color`. For example:

```html
<option data-size="S" data-color="Red" value="S / Red">S / Red</option>
```

To get the data-values you can use the `dataset` keyword. To select an element you can use attribute-selectors. For example:

```js
const variant_type = this.dataset.type;

$('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"])')
```

With the `data-type` from the `select.variant` you could define which data-attribute of `select[name="id"]` you want to select. For example:

```js
$('[data-' + other_type + '="' + other_val + '"]')
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.variant').change(function() {
    const val = this.value;
    const variant_type = this.dataset.type;
    const other_type = $('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"])')[0].dataset.type;

    $('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"]) option').attr('disabled', false);
    $('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"]) option').each(function() {
      const other_val = this.value;

      if (!$('option').is('[data-' + variant_type + '="' + val + 
        '"][data-' + other_type + '="' + other_val + '"]')) {
        this.disabled = true;
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <select class="variant" data-type="size">
    <option></option>
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
  </select>
  <select class="variant" data-type="color">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name="id">
    <option></option>
    <option data-size="M" data-color="Grey" value="M / Grey">M / Grey</option>
    <option data-size="L" data-color="Grey" value="L / Grey">L / Grey</option>
    <option data-size="S" data-color="Red" value="S / Red">S / Red</option>
    <option data-size="L" data-color="Red" value="L / Red">L / Red</option>
    <option data-size="M" data-color="White" value="M / White">M / White</option>
    <option data-size="L" data-color="White" value="L / White">L / White</option>
    <option data-size="XL" data-color="Red" value="XL / Red">XL / Red</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

---

If you want to auto update the third select when both `select.variant` are chosen you could define a data object. For example:

```js
let selected = {};
```

With each call of the `change` handler you would update the object with the `data-type` and the value (add a new entry to the object or overwrite an existing one):

```js
selected[variant_type] = val;
```

After that you would update the third `select` (add the `selected` attribute to the fitting option), but only if both `select.variant` were chosen, which means that both got an entry in the data object:

```js
if (selected[variant_type] && selected[other_type]) {...}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let selected = {};
  
  $('.variant').change(function() {
    const val = this.value;
    const variant_type = this.dataset.type;
    const other_type = $('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"])')[0].dataset.type;

    selected[variant_type] = val;

    $('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"]) option').attr('disabled', false);
    $('.variant:not([data-type="' + variant_type + '"]) option').each(function() {
      const other_val = this.value;

      if (!$('option').is('[data-' + variant_type + '="' + val + 
        '"][data-' + other_type + '="' + other_val + '"]')) {
        this.disabled = true;
      }
    });

    if (selected[variant_type] && selected[other_type]) {
      $('option[data-' + variant_type + '="' + selected[variant_type] + 
        '"][data-' + other_type + '="' + selected[other_type] + '"]'
        )[0].selected = true;
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <select class="variant" data-type="size">
    <option></option>
    <option value="S">S</option>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="L">L</option>
    <option value="XL">XL</option>
  </select>
  <select class="variant" data-type="color">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="White">White</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name="id">
    <option></option>
    <option data-size="M" data-color="Grey" value="M / Grey">M / Grey</option>
    <option data-size="L" data-color="Grey" value="L / Grey">L / Grey</option>
    <option data-size="S" data-color="Red" value="S / Red">S / Red</option>
    <option data-size="L" data-color="Red" value="L / Red">L / Red</option>
    <option data-size="M" data-color="White" value="M / White">M / White</option>
    <option data-size="L" data-color="White" value="L / White">L / White</option>
    <option data-size="XL" data-color="Red" value="XL / Red">XL / Red</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: @AnupamMistry I updated my answer with your "XL"-question from the comments. Please test it...

Comment: I test your given snippets, they all are working well. But the `data-attributes` are suitable to my code. But I don't want to use `const val = this.value.toLowerCase();` because my data values in `capitalize`. `data-size="XL"`  `data-color="Grey"`.

Comment: Also I want to auto select `name="id"` as I select  both dropdown `class="variant"`. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68173488/how-to-auto-select-option-depending-on-another-dropdowns-value).

Comment: I removed `toLowerCase()` in the pure `data-attributes` example. I will see if i can add the auto selection, although it wasn't part of the question...

Comment: I added the auto update to the second example and fixed a bug: instead of `$('.variant option').attr('disabled', false);` it should be `$('.variant:not(.' + variant_type + ') option').attr('disabled', false);`. Otherwise all disabled option are reenabled, so that you could for example after selecting another color select all colors again (M -> Grey -> White -> Red would now be selectable)

Comment: Thanks [biberman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15377355/biberman) for good efforts. But can `const val` will get by `$(this).parent('form').find('.variant').children('data-size')` insted of `this.value`.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean. In the duplicate question that you asked yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68296037/how-to-hide-and-auto-select-option-using-data-attributes#comment120737453_68296037) the solution is also with `const val = this.value;`

Comment: I have multiple forms like that. So whenever I select another form's dropdown value, It will be also changed in all `name="id"` dropdowns. So for that, I want to use the parent  in `const val`. Somthing like `$(this).parent('form').find('.variant').children('data-size')`  insted of `this.value`

Comment: Hi. How can I reset the change function to the initial state with a button click?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same idea as @biberman but my code allows you to change your `.variants`'s second class to whatever you like - it could be `<select class="variant size">` or `<select class="variant variant1">` or whatever

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  function gatherCombinations () {
    var combos = $('select[name="id"] > option');
    var result = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
      var comboVal = $(combos[i]).val();
      var comboValArr = comboVal.split(" / ");
      
      result.push(comboValArr);
    }
    
    return result;
  }
  
  function isExistingCombination (var1, var2) {
    var combinations = gatherCombinations();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < combinations.length; i++) {
      var combo = combinations[i];
      
      if (combo.indexOf(var1) >= 0 && combo.indexOf(var2) >= 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    
    return false;
  }
  
  $('.variant').on('change', function() {
    var variantType = $(this).attr('data-var');
    var variantVal = $(this).val();
    var otherVariants = $('.variant:not(.' + variantType + ')');
    var otherVariantsOptions = $('.variant:not(.' + variantType + ') > option');
    
    otherVariantsOptions.show();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < otherVariantsOptions.length; i++) {
      var otherVariantOptionVal = $(otherVariantsOptions[i]).val();
      
      if (isExistingCombination(variantVal, otherVariantOptionVal) == false) {
        $(otherVariantsOptions[i]).hide();
      }
    }
    
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <select class="variant size" data-var="size">
   <option value="S">S</option>
   <option value="M">M</option>
   <option value="L">L</option>
  </select>
  <select class="variant color" data-var="color">
   <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
   <option value="Red">Red</option>
   <option value="White">White</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name="id">
   <option value="M / Grey">M / Grey</option>
   <option value="L / Grey">L / Grey</option>
   <option value="S / Red">S / Red</option>
   <option value="L / Red">L / Red</option>
   <option value="M / White">M / White</option>
   <option value="L / White">L / White</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: How It will work when I have `XL / Red`, value in `name=id` dropdown. Because when I select `L` and `Red` it will show `XL / Red`  not the `L / Red`