# Jquery show selected a value from a dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a code that is used to select certain elements, the code works great when you click on the geticon button and it shows the right option value. The problem is I am not sure how to show the selected option value onSelect of the dropdown (instead of the button).

Here is my Jsfiddle

```js
       $(document).ready(function() {
       
          $('#getIcon').asIconPicker();
          $('#api-get-click').click(function() {
            var html = '<div>Your choice is "' + $('#getIcon').asIconPicker('get') + '"</div>';
            $(html).prependTo($('#api-get-info'));
            return false;
          });
          
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/prism.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/dist/css/asIconPicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/asTooltip.min.css">
    
     <script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/jquery.toc.js"></script>
      <script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/prism.js"></script>
      <script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/jquery-asTooltip.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/jquery-asScrollbar.js"></script>
      <script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/dist/jquery-asIconPicker.js"></script>
      
     <section>
            <span id="toc8"></span>
            <h3>Get()</h3>
            <pre class="has-example">
            <div class="example">
              <select id="getIcon" name="default" class="getIcon">
                            <option>fa-user</option>
                            <option>fa-search</option>
                            <option>fa-caret-right</option>
                            <option>fa-star</option>
                            <option>fa-times</option>
                            <option>fa-refresh</option>
                            <option>fa-rocket</option>
                            <option>fa-eye</option>
                            <option>fa-tag</option>
                            <option>fa-bookmark</option>
                            <option>fa-heart</option>
                            <option>fa-adn</option>
                            <option>fa-cloud-upload</option>
                            <option>fa-phone-square</option>
                            <option>fa-cog</option>
                            <option>fa-wrench</option>
                            <option>fa-volume-down</option>
                            <option>fa-caret-down</option>
                            <option>fa-caret-up</option>
                            <option>fa-caret-left</option>
                            <option>fa-thumbs-up</option>
                        </select>
              <button id="api-get-click">getIcon</button>
            </div>
            <div class="example" id="api-get-info"></div>
          </section>
```

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Comment: do you want to display value text instead of icons?

Comment: Yes, we have to show text instead of icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [jquery-asIconPicker](https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asIconPicker) plugin on the `<select>` element... and the plugin does not seem to have a built-in `change` event. So you can simply use another selector for your click event listener: `.asIconPicker-list`.

A very short setTimeout will make sure that the method `.asIconPicker('get')` is applied after the selection is made.

That will work fine if there is only one instance of the plugin in the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#getIcon').asIconPicker();

  // Change the selector here
  $('.asIconPicker-list').click(function() {
  
    setTimeout(function(){
      var html = '<div>Your choice is "' + $('#getIcon').asIconPicker('get') + '"</div>';
      $(html).prependTo($('#api-get-info'));
    },1)
    //return false; // This prevents the dropdown from closing
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/prism.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/dist/css/asIconPicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/css/asTooltip.min.css">

<script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/jquery.toc.js"></script>
<script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/prism.js"></script>
<script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/jquery-asTooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/js/jquery-asScrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://wplugin.strandwebsites.com/stack/dist/jquery-asIconPicker.js"></script>

<section>
  <span id="toc8"></span>
  <h3>Get()</h3>
  <pre class="has-example">
            <div class="example">
              <select id="getIcon" name="default" class="getIcon">
                            <option>fa-user</option>
                            <option>fa-search</option>
                            <option>fa-caret-right</option>
                            <option>fa-star</option>
                            <option>fa-times</option>
                            <option>fa-refresh</option>
                            <option>fa-rocket</option>
                            <option>fa-eye</option>
                            <option>fa-tag</option>
                            <option>fa-bookmark</option>
                            <option>fa-heart</option>
                            <option>fa-adn</option>
                            <option>fa-cloud-upload</option>
                            <option>fa-phone-square</option>
                            <option>fa-cog</option>
                            <option>fa-wrench</option>
                            <option>fa-volume-down</option>
                            <option>fa-caret-down</option>
                            <option>fa-caret-up</option>
                            <option>fa-caret-left</option>
                            <option>fa-thumbs-up</option>
                        </select>
            </div>
            <div class="example" id="api-get-info"></div>
          </section>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's shown the previously selected item.

Comment: I didn't notice... But I edited with a fix.

Comment: Yes, it's working for, Thank you very much.

Comment: If we can search any icon and select any icon then it's not working. what is the issue with this.

Comment: I don't understand that. I suggest you to open a new question specifically about this, with your current code.